# Call Custom function after binding customer name in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.2

I have updated the customer name using ko.

After binding customer name, I want to add one custom class.

```
<li class="customer-welcome">
        <span class="customer-name"
              role="link"
              tabindex="0"
              data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
              data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname"></span>
            <button type="button"
                    class="action switch"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    data-action="customer-menu-toggle">
                <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
```

How to call the custom function after binding customer name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/header/loginlink.phtml

Paste Below Span inside the My account section in loginlink.phtml file

```
 <span class="bold" data-mage-init='{"js/loggedusername":{}}'>My Account</span>
```

Create a New js file  named loggedusername.js in the below path

> app/design/frontend/{theme}/{theme_name}/web/js/loggedusername.js

```
define([
    "jquery", "Magento_Customer/js/customer-data"
], function($, customerData) {
    "use strict";
    return function (config, element) {
        var firstname = customerData.get('customer')().firstname;

        if (typeof (firstname) === "undefined") {
            customerData.reload('customer');
        }
        var check = setInterval(function () {
            var firstname = customerData.get('customer')().firstname;
            if (firstname) {
                $(element).text('Hi, ' + firstname);
                 $(element).addClass('your_class_name_here')
                clearInterval(check);
            }
        }, 500);
    };
});
```

**In this solution not based on knockout js, But it works perfectly** .Please follow if you want , Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try below method...

```
<span data-bind="text: customer().fullname, css: {
                'custom-class' :  customer().fullname
                }">
</span>
```

Not tested in my env

Comment: Its working, thanks.